# cvs2svn mime types

Tags: cvs, cvs2svn

In order to take in account Richard's comment and Steen's answer of I have to specify independently of type mime file and independently of the type file marked in CVS, I am looking for how to treat all files as binary file in cvs2svn ? Perhaps is not possible ?

Please Richard (or others), may you tell me how to know the marked type in CVS for a given file ?

---

Hello,
How to treat all files as binary file ?
All 16 pass (of cvs2svn) are correctly done but several binary files are corrupted (like .gif). There are not treated as binary file!

The command line I used is:

```
python C:\noinstaller\cvs2svn-2.2.0\cvs2svn -s "SVN_REPO" "CVS_REPO" --use-cvs
--encoding=latin1 --mime-types=svn-mime-types --eol-from-mime-type 
--keywords-off --sort=C:\noinstaller\UnxUtils\usr\local\wbin\sort.exe
```

After the reading of the [CVS2SVN FAQ](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/faq.html), I had tried many other options, but same the same file are always corrupted.

Thanks. Christian.

Comment: Quick question: are the gif files marked as binary in CVS?

Comment: Please Richard May you tell me How to know the marked type in CVS for a given file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deduce it is impossible to force cvs2svn to consider all files as binary file.

Comment: Sorry you're having no luck; here's yet another post that help http://markmail.org/thread/iup7e3kdhsurgvja

Answer (score 4):

Subversion use a heuritic algorithm to determine whether a file is binary or not. Firstly, it checks if the `mime-types-file` configuration parameter is set and uses this to map files to mime-types. If not such configuration is found, it looks at the 1024 first bytes, and if more than 15% are not within ASCII range or any of them are null values, the file is considered binary. To specifically set a mime-type of a given file-type, you must use [auto props](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.auto).

Please note that if subversion determines your file to be of mime-type `image/x-xbitmap` or `image/x-xpixmap`, it will be treated as a text file

Auto-props affect the `svn add` and `svn import` actions and are set using the [runtime configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.confarea.html), which are specified through either command line options or in the *config* file for subversion, found in the subversion installation conf directory.
The following values should be set:

```
# default is 'no', so we enable auto props with
enable-auto-props = yes

# specify absolute path to mime.types like file, e.g.
mime-types-file = /etc/mime.types
```

This should map your binary files correctly.

EDIT: From the [cvs2svn](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2svn.html) manual:

> --auto-props=FILE
>
> Specify a file in the format of Subversion's config file, whose
>   [auto-props] section can be used to set arbitrary properties on
>   files in the Subversion repository based on their filenames. (The
>   [auto-props] section header must be present; other sections of the
>   config file, including the enable-auto-props setting, are ignored.)
>   Filenames are matched to the filename patterns case-insensitively,
>   consistent with Subversion's behavior. The auto-props file might
>   have content like this:
>
> ```
> [auto-props]
> *.txt = svn:mime-type=text/plain;svn:eol-style=native
> *.doc = svn:mime-type=application/msword;!svn:eol-style
> ```

So, using the command line switch `--auto-props` and an auto-props
file, you should be able to get the wanted functionality of the
`cvs2svn` script

Comment: I work with brainkiller, and I thank you for your answer (+1 by the way). However it seems the problem is within the mime-types-file option: out "mime-types" file does not appear to be taken into account. If it was, we could make sure everything is treated as binary.

Answer (score 3):

As to the question of how to have cvs2svn treat all files as binary, I can only point to the section in the FAQ relating to [EOL](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/faq.html#eol-fixup)

> Starting with version 2.0, the default behavior of cvs2svn is to treat all files as binary except those explicitly determined to be text.

Also from the FAQ:

> If a file is marked as binary in CVS (with cvs admin -kb, then cvs2svn will always treat the file as binary.

To see if a file is marked as binary, look for the -kb option on the file in CVS.  In WinCVS, there are columns for this as well as Encoding.

Unfortunately, I don't have a solution for you, but I would try and simplify your command arguments to focus on what exactly isn't working right for those files.  Using an --auto-props file will give you ultimate control over each file.  If your CVS file is "clean" (meaning all files are properly committed as text and binary), the --default-style=native parameter supposedly gives the best results.

Good luck and let us know what works for you.

Comment: Thank you Richard, and +1 for those pointers. Brainkiller and I are looking into it right now. One issue is that we cvs2svn on a Windows platform, from a CVS repo from Unix...

Comment: @VonC: Funny, I am in the process of doing the same thing.  CVS on Unix -> SVN on Windows.  Unfortunately, SOX prevents me from touching the systems so I can't experiment with you.  At any rate, our binaries are working fine using --default-style=native.

Comment: @Richard Morgan: are you using the python-script cvs2svn in 2.2.0 version ?

Comment: @VonC: actually, I think it's just 2.0.  Looks like I should investigate upgrading.  Thanks.